# Firebase Analytics for web apps (after Firebase expansion)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a web application with Firebase and yesterday they released their expansion with all great new features. However, the Analytics section is now only available for Android and IOS apps, but I need to check the general performances and data usage of my web app as before. Is there a way to see those statistics, to prevent my app of being turned off if I exceed my limits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase is a new analytics product for tracking usage and engagement in mobile and web applications.

But those are a little different than the old reporting on usage of the database.

As you say, the reporting is important for monitoring your usage of the database, it's something we're looking into bringing to the new Firebase console as well, so stay tuned.

Comment: It's been over a year... Any update on when we can expect a firebase traffic monitoring tool for web apps? I really would like to get an idea of all firebase transactions that are happening in my web app.

Comment: We still recommend using Google Analytics for engagement and usage - we've transitioned Firebase Analytics to Google Analytics for Firebase back at I/O as measure of how much we're bringing the products together. 

For database profiling purposes, we did release this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Comment: Is there a way to use it with hybrid mobile apps, Ionic/Angular? I just can't find any info for that, and there are no some files, which are using in docs/tutorials.

Comment: Not official support, but there are some plugins for hybrid apps. See https://pointdeveloper.com/firebase-analytics-for-ionic-apps-logging-custom-events/ as an example

Comment: For hybrid apps this might also be useful.
- https://github.com/firebase/analytics-webview