# Firebase analytics and Python client API

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there any Python library which can be used to collect and send information (data) to Firebase analytics? I would use this library in an application that I am developing.

Edit: Thanks for downvoting without informing me what is the reason for.

Edit 2: Of course I have found several APIs. But most of the APIs are for admin purposes. I know that this can be used as well but maybe there is a simplified version used for clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Google Analytics for Firebase (originally called Firebase Analytics) has supported client SDKs for Android and iOS. There is no public API to call Google Analytics for Firebase from platforms other than Android and iOS.

Also see:

- [How can i use the NEW Firebase Analytics feature with a webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330412/how-can-i-use-the-new-firebase-analytics-feature-with-a-webapp)
- [Firebase Analytics for web apps (after Firebase expansion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325871/firebase-analytics-for-web-apps-after-firebase-expansion)
- [Firebase analytics from remote REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355752/firebase-analytics-from-remote-rest-api)
- [Firebase Analytics Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974885/firebase-analytics-rest-api)

Comment: Thank You! I have thought that there are no APIs for Python.

Answer (score 1):

people downvoted because a simple google search would net you a link to the github page of the firebase api wrapper in python that can be found here: https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase

EDIT: I think its imposiible since there is no api for firebase analytics, just the regular firebase.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have written some explanation. Thank you for the link. I actually already know that API posted on a GitHub. It is even cited somewhere on a Firebase web page.

Comment: @Matphy see edit.